# How to select specific class with Scrapy

Tags: html, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to scrape a page that contains specific info.
The url:https://www.artisans-du-batiment.com/trouver-un-artisan-qualifie/?job=Charpentier&place=35000%2F35900
I want to select a class for each carpenter, so I try response.css('div.a-artisanTease to-animate'), but it gives no selection. What might be the problem?

Thanks.

I've tried several different paths.
I need the scrapy to select all separate carpenters that are on the page, so I can later collect info for all search results

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason is because you need a specific cookie for the server to serve you the full html for the page.  Also your css selector expression is wrong.

The cookie needed is `"tarteaucitron=!googletagmanager=wait"` and the correct css expression would be `div.a-artisanTease.to-animate`

For example using scrapy shell:

```py
In [1]: fetch(scrapy.Request("https://www.artisans-du-batiment.com/trouver-un-artisan-qualifie/?job=Charpentier&place=35000%2F35900", h
   ...: eaders = {"cookies": "tarteaucitron=!googletagmanager=wait"}))
2023-10-17 00:43:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-10-17 00:43:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.artisans-du-batiment.com/trouver-un-artisan-qualifie/?job=Charpentier&place=35000%2F35900> (referer: None)

In [2]: response.css("div.a-artisanTease.to-animate")
Out[2]:
[<Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>,
 <Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-artisanTease ')) and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' to-animate '))]" data='<div class="a-artisanTease to-animate...'>]
```

```
fetch(scrapy.Request("https://www.artisans-du-batiment.com/trouver-un-artisan-qualifie/?job=Charpentier&place=35000%2F35900", headers = {"cookies": "tarteaucitron=!googletagmanager=wait"}))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, anyway, once I copy the fetch(scrapy..... part I get invalid syntax error, pointing to h letter

Comment: @user2502913 that is because there is a line continuation....

Comment: @user2502913 I just edited the answer at the bottom with the actual line you want to copy and paste

Comment: seems to be working now, but I struggle to extract address and e-mail address. For address I use customer.xpath("//div[@class='a-artisanTease__address']/span/text()").get() but I get '\n        11 square general aubree                        35200 RENNES, I would need '11 square general aubree' and ''35200 Rennes' separately. For email I use customer.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'mailto')]/text").get() but I do not get any answer

Answer (score -1):

The reason you can't retrieve data with Scrapy is that this webpage is written in JavaScript. Scrapy cannot assist you in this case. You need to use a library that can handle JavaScript, such as Selenium or Splash, to retrieve data from this webpage.

I recommend using XPath selectors instead of CSS selectors, as XPath offers many useful options for searching text in the DOM. The equivalent XPath code for your code would be:

//div[@class='a-artisanTease to-animate']

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).